# How to change Mathematical ODE code to Python

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, ode, odeint

I am given the following code within `Mathematica`

```
solution = NDSolve[{\[CapitalOmega]\[CapitalLambda]'[x] == 
(1 - \[CapitalOmega]\[CapitalLambda][x]) \[CapitalOmega]\[CapitalLambda][x] ((1 - \[CapitalOmega]\[CapitalLambda][x])^((1 - \[Delta])/(4 -\2 \[Delta]))  \[CapitalOmega]\[CapitalLambda][x]^(1/(4 - 2 \[Delta]))), \[CapitalOmega]\[CapitalLambda][0] == \[CapitalOmega]\[CapitalLambda]f}, \[CapitalOmega]\\[CapitalLambda], {x, xi, xf}];
```

I want to write it in Python, using `ODEINT`
but I really do not understand the way of writing it, because it sends `error1 of complex number.

```
def OD_H(z, od, delt):
    dMdt = od * (1 - od) * ((1 - od)**((1 - delt)/(4-2*delt)) * od**(1/(2 *(2-delt))))
    return dMdt                                                                                                                      

def ant(z, od0, delt):
    z1 = 0
    od = odeint(OD_H, od0, [z1, z], args=(delt,))[-1]       
    return od     

for z in np.arange(0,3.1,0.1):
    print(ant(z, 0.7, 1.1))
```

the error is

`od = odeint(OD_H, od0, [z1, z], args=(delt,))[-1]
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\odepack.py", line 244, in odeint
    int(bool(tfirst)))
TypeError: can't convert complex to float`

Comment: have you read the documentation of odeint?

Comment: @BlueRineS Yes and I know how to use it as I have done many times before, but this time Iva got an unknown error and by the way I would like to exactly translate this lines of `Mathematica` to `Python`

Comment: You've got an unknown error? Can you plase share it exactly in your post? including entire stack trace, and including entire code of yourself of what you've tried so far?

Comment: within 1 mins, I will update, wait plz

Comment: If the signature is ``callable(t, y, ...)``, then the argument
        `tfirst` must be set ``True`` ?

Comment: @Joe I couldnt get your point

Comment: Look at the doc to `odeint`, last keyword.

Comment: @Joe  My problem is, when I use mathematica, I get the answer, but using ODINT I get error

Comment: Hard to tell what fails here. For debugging, please start with a simple equation that works, maybe use an example from the odeint docs and bit by bit add complexity. Then tell us where it fails.

Comment: @joe ODINT works well, this time is weird. I found it conflict with `(1-od)**` in the equation. The Mmathematica solves it easily but ODEINT make it impossible. I should know why.

Comment: I get `ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power`, which is more logical. What you get is a follow-up error of a sudden type change from real to complex. What are the python and scipy versions that you use?

Comment: Also, can you indicate what the dependent and independent variables are? You possibly need to give `tfirst=True` to get any correct integration at all. With that the integration proceeds without error.

Comment: @LutzL Python 3.6.3, Scipy and Numpy latest version.

Comment: Then there were changes that made it too clever for their own good, automatically changing results of rational power to complex whenever no real results exist. Internally, `odeint` passes the derivative values to Fortran code working on real numbers, requiring to convert a complex number to a real, which is not possible without numerical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `odeint` call we learn that you use `z` as time variable and `od` as space/state variable. As your derivatives function has the time first, and the default in `odeint` is to have the state first, you need to set the option `tfirst=True`. With that change there are no errors. You get the same values with less computation by using the full power of `odeint` in giving it a list of all desired sampling points

```
z = np.arange(0,3.1,0.1)
od = odeint(OD_H, od0, z, args=(delt,), tfirst=True)
```

where then the pairs `z[k], od[k]` correspond to the argument-value pairs that you compute in the loop.

Comment: It is solved, you know, I did this but I got the same error. I copied and pasted the code step by step in a new python file, and I ran it for each copied-pasted step, every thing was correct until the whole code was copied and pasted. Now I do not get error while I do not change anything at all

Comment: this is my 3rd time that in one python shell I got error, but in a new one everything is correct.

Comment: So you have something in the old workspace that changes how the python interpreter works. You would have to analyze the whole command history of that session to find out what it could be. If in a newly started shell everything is good, then the problem is solved? If the problem occurs in a larger script, reduce the larger script as much as possible while retaining the error, either you find the error source or you can ask a new good question.

Comment: Yes the `tfirst=True` made it correct. It is now what `NDSolve` of mathematica does. I have never used tfirst=True before.

Comment: It is a relatively new option, possibly with the same overhaul that gave the `solve_ivp` interface.